# Counting and Summing the number of time an observation occurs by group in SAS

Tags: count, sas, output

Say I have the following Data:

```
   Ad_Code     Employers          State    City
    246         McDonald           CA      Los Angeles
    345         Mcdonald           CA      Los Angeles
    4547        Mcdonald           CA      Los Angeles
    4563        TJMax              CA      SanFran
    5475        TJMax              CA      SanFran
    23          TJMax              CA      SanFran
    6           BestBuy            CA      SanFran
    66747       BestBUy            CA      SanFran
    7           Walmart            CA      Los Angeles
    71          Walmart            CA      Lost Angeles
```

Now I want to create a program which will spit out the Top 2 employers with most ads per city in a state, and also per state. So for example for Los Angeles, the Top 2 employers will be McDonald and Walmart, while for San Fran it will be TJMax and Best Buy.And for the state of California as a whole, the top two employers will be TJMax and BestBuy. The other part of my problem is creating a sort of "count" method from the AD_Code. So my excel tables (per sheet for each city and then the state) will look like the following:

Sheet 1 (state_CA)

```
Employer   Count 
TJMAX        3
BestBuy      3
```

Sheet 2 (City_LA)

```
 City   Employer   Count
  LA    McDonald    3
  LA    Walmart     2
```

Sheet 3 (City_SF)

```
 City   Employer   Count
  SF    TJMAX       3
  SF    BestBuy     2
```

Also, how can I obtain the Count from the Ad_code? Is there a way to count the number of time a value appears in the AD_code column and then assign it a value of 1 and then sum all of the values that appear in Ad_code and put it under a new column header named Count? How would I go about accomplishing such a task? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about code you've written, not a code-writing service.  Please look online for the documentation of procedures like `PROC RANK` or `PROC MEANS`, make an attempt to solve this, and then come back with specific questions.

Comment: Thanks joe. I actually wasn't looking for someone to write me a code, but just to guide me on some procedures that I could use to accomplish such a task.

Answer (score 2):

The general way I'd approach this:

1. `PROC MEANS`, with a `class` statement using both grouping variables, and `type` statement defining the kinds of combinations of those grouping variables you want (sounds like just the 1 way, so you could even use `ways=1`).  Output to a dataset the statistics you want.
2. Use a data step or `proc rank` to calculate the ranks, and save only the ones you want (so `rank le 2` or some such).
3. Take the output dataset and export it using `proc export` with `where` clauses, or if you are writing many exports, use a data-driven approach to generate macro calls to a macro that runs your proc export for you.  Search 'data-driven programming SAS' for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks Joe. This is quite helpful. For output purposes, I am actually using ODS Tagsets...I like it quite a lot. I think the only problem for me right now is figuring out how to do some sort of count for the AD_Code, where it would assign a value of 1 whenever there is a code present and then add up all of those 1's to a final Count number.

Comment: Look at proc means and the N statistic